# How to get referer with subpath when redirect from subpath?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Origin URL: http://localhost:5174/about/
Redirect URL: http://localhost:3000

When i click link button in Origin APP i want to see in Redirect App that referer is `http://localhost:5174/about/` but using `document.referer` only shows main domain `http://localhost:5174`

Comment: Guess: Your system is probably setting a [`Referrer-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy), likely either `origin` or `origin-when-cross-origin`.